# Face detection using OpenCV Java Android's camera onPreviewFrame()'s byte[] data does not work

Tags: java, android, opencv, face-detection, portrait

I am trying to used OpenCV java wrapper to detect faces in an app.

1) The app is using front-facing camera in potrait mode.

2) The preview is displayed inside a SurfaceView.

3) I am using Android's onPreviewFrame()'s `byte[]` data and changing it into OpenCV format to detect the faces using OpenCV.

4) I send the coordinates detected by `mJavaDetector` to a `View` class to be drawn on a instance of the drawingView surface.

When I start the application, there are no errors but no rectangle is drawn. The

`Log.v(TAG, "Length of facesArray" + facesArray.length);`

inside `SurfaceChanged` is also not displayed. Is it because the `onPreviewFrame()` is not called or a problem with my OpenCV implementation or other problems?

I have attached my codes below.

```
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

         /**if(previewing){
               //mCamera.stopFaceDetection();
               mCamera.stopPreview();
               previewing = false;
              }**/

              if (mCamera != null){
               try {
                   mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                   mCamera.startPreview();
                   mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
                        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera mCamera) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "ON Preview frame");
                            int mAbsoluteFaceSize   = 0;


                            int width = surfaceView.getWidth();
                            int height = surfaceView.getHeight();
                            Mat img = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                            Mat gray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
                            img.put(0, 0, data);        

                            Imgproc.cvtColor(img, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2GRAY);

                            MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

                            if (mJavaDetector != null)
                                mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 2, // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                                        new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());

                            Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();

                            Log.v(TAG, "Length of facesArray" + facesArray.length);

                            if(facesArray != null){
                                drawingView.setHaveFace(true);
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++){
                                double l = facesArray[i].tl().x;
                                double t = facesArray[i].tl().y;
                                double r = facesArray[i].br().x;
                                double b = facesArray[i].br().y;
                                drawingView.setCoordinates(l, t, r, b);
                            }

                        }
                        });

                /**prompt.setText(String.valueOf(
                  "Max Face: " + mCamera.getParameters().getMaxNumDetectedFaces()));
                  mCamera.startFaceDetection();
                previewing = true;**/
               } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
               }
              }
    }
```

Class DrawingView:

```
private class DrawingView extends View{

          boolean haveFace;
          Paint drawingPaint;
          float left;
          float top;
          float right;
          float bottom;

          public DrawingView(Context context) {
           super(context);
           haveFace = false;
           drawingPaint = new Paint();
           drawingPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
           drawingPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
           drawingPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
          }

          public void setHaveFace(boolean h){
           haveFace = h;
          }

          public void setCoordinates(double l,double t, double r, double b){
              left = (float)l;
              top = (float)t;
              right = (float)r;
              bottom = (float)b;
          }
          @Override
          protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            if(haveFace){
                canvas.drawRect(
                           left, top, right, bottom,  
                           drawingPaint);
            }
            else{
                canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
          }
         }
```

My drawingView declaration in `onCreate()`:

```
  drawingView = new DrawingView(this);
    LayoutParams layoutParamsDrawing 
     = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 
       LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    this.addContentView(drawingView, layoutParamsDrawing);
```

Comment: the byte[] is not a bitmap, it is a jpg/png/whatever format the camera uses.

Comment: @njk2 from the documentation its written "the contents of the preview frame in the format defined by ImageFormat, which can be queried with getPreviewFormat(). If setPreviewFormat(int) is never called, the default will be the YCbCr_420_SP (NV21) format." I never called setPreviewFormat, so I need to convert the NV21 to bitmap before converting it to OpenCV frame??

Comment: yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695507/converting-bitmaprgb-565-to-grayscale8-bit-android

Comment: I had a if condition statement checking for the format of the preview image using getPreviewFormat but I found out it is always returning 0 (unknown format) in my Nexus 4. When I removed the condition everything works fine. The data coming to onPreviewFrame is indeed in the default format, NV21. Weird problem with getPreviewFormat(). Anyway thx.